# How to submit to the seller dashboard

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I've developed a webpart using the SharePoint framework. I now need to submit it to the seller dashboard so that my customers can use it. When I go to submit the generated .sppkg file (I'm assuming this is the right file?) it tells me the manifest is missing the SupportedLocales option.

Is this the right file to submit? And if it is, how do I add this option to the manifest generated by `gulp package-solution`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot publish SPFx solution to the store.

Its not supported yet.

> The SharePoint Framework solutions do not, at the time of writing,
>   have a store where you can download and install solutions,...

What you can do is upload the package(`.sppkg`) to a tenant or a site collection app catalog site and then it will be available in the site collection(s) where you want it.

Reference - [SharePoint Framework (SPFx) enterprise guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/enterprise-guidance)